# Difference between ConnectionTimeoutException and SSLException with message "Connection timed out"

Tags: java, android, http, https, apache-httpclient-4.x

On my Android code (using Apache HTTP Client) I have already set the following parameters :

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 30 * SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 30 * SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
```

I am connecting to an HTTPS web-service. On slow networks, I get a `ConnectionTimeoutException` after expected 30 seconds (and I retry then) ; but there are "few" cases (with no pattern I could observe), I get either of these :

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0xe71160: I/O error during
>   system call, Connection timed out  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write
>   error: ssl=0xe71160: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe

I got this code from SO, which is still under test :

```
registry.register(new Scheme("https", 
    SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getHttpSocketFactory(30 * SECOND_IN_MILLIS, null), 443));
```

I can understand Connection establishment timeout and socket timeout - my query is do we really need this 3rd timeout for SSL ? How is the purpose different from SO_TIMEOUT ?

PS : These excepions seem to come in picture while reading/writing data - which should have resulted in data loss - but I cannot observe that either.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the `ConnectionTimeoutException` occurs when no connection can be established at all. That means the server is not reachable at all.

The `SSLException` occurs when the connection was established already but during the SSL handshake the connection times out. Because the timeout occurs after the SSL handshake has started the `SSLException` is thrown as higher level exception.

You can try to check if a `ConnectionTimeoutException` is entered as the cause of the `SSLException`.